# Foundation orbit-content-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

When you click on the content of orbit content slider it goes to the next slide some kinda calling "self.next" in the js I think, I want to disable that, any ideas?

Comment: Really? no one? please explain why this can't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've achieved till now:

there's this line in the foundation.js file:
container.on('click', '[data-orbit-slide]', self.link_bullet);

I've commented it out and now I can safely put a tabbed div in the slides without auto sliding on click, but the indicator bullets does not work on click, they just show which slide is active right now as you could guessed by commenting out that line....
if there could be anything that I could achieve better functionality please do mention it, Y'ALL